# Taking a series of inputs and calculating the minimum, maximum, total and average but stopping once a negative number is inputted

Tags: python

When i enter a negative number it doesn't stop my while loop and instead keeps asking for inputs. List works fine and gets the correct values

```
def positive_statistics():
    total = 0
    count = 0
    a = []
    while True:
        number = float(input("Input a positive Number:"))
        if number < 0:
            break
        a.append(number)
        total = total + number
        count = count + 1
    a.sort()
    maximum = a.pop()
    minimum = a.pop(0)
    average = total / count
    return minimum, maximum, total, average
```

expected it to stop asking for inputs when a number < 0 is entered

```
Input a positive Number:4
Input a positive Number:8
Input a positive Number:3
Input a positive Number:-1
Input a positive Number:-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\helka\eclipse\ws\helk0000_l07\src\t05.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(f"{positive_statistics()}")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\helka\eclipse\ws\helk0000_l07\src\functions.py", line 77, in positive_statistics
    maximum = a.pop()
              ^^^^^^^
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

```
from functions import positive_statistics
positive_statistics()
print(f"{positive_statistics()}")
```

Comment: When I enter a negative number it stops prompting. Can you show us an example run of this function that demonstrated this behaviour?

Comment: Then you haven't shared all of the necessary information for us to be able to help you. The function you've shown us doesn't require any other code to execute, and works correctly when executed, so the error is with something you haven't shown us.

Comment: last line is what im using the call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've called the function once and then discarded that information, then called it *again* to print it. This explains the symptoms you're seeing.

You correctly read in 4, 8, and 3 in the first call, and -1 terminates the loop. The second time you call the function you immediately give it -1, which means the list inside the function is empty, and trying to pop from it gives you an exception.

Instead call the function and store the results.

```
from functions import positive_statistics

result = positive_statistics()
print(f"{results}")
```

Comment: perfect, thank you that makes much more sense. Appreciate the patience